# Calling multiple functions with Zend AMF and one NetConnection?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, remoting, zend-amf

I have Zend AMF working great in my application, but I'm trying to figure out how to call multiple asynchronous functions with a single connection. For example, let's say I have a service called "MyService" and two functions called "init" and "getData". Can I create a connection, call "MyService.init" THEN "MyService.getData" within the same remote object? If so, how...if not, what is a better solution?

Of course, in this scenario, I can just combine init and getData into one function...but, the problem in the actual scenario is that there are many more methods that will need to run after "init".  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108864/php-how-to-call-a-class-in-zendamf) that I asked here I believe for the same reason as yours.  I would love to know how to call multiple methods or even better, classes over one connection.

Anyway, in your case where you are talking about methods, with no answer on how to call them from the flex side, I would either make a 3rd method that calls those two, or allow some kind of object or parameter passing for init and let init call getData.

Another thought - maybe you need to consider what is happening in init and whether you really need it or need to call it directly from the client - for example, in order to getData (or put or etc), you always have to have been initialized?  So getData should probably check to see if it has been initialized and init if it has not.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Szretter. I'm marking this as answered not because I have found the solution to call multiple functions, but because I was able to combine some functions and/or make multiple asynchronous calls. Thanks again for the thoughts.